# HTML & CSS - iFrame pointer-events when scrolling on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am having a problem with scrolling using iFrame. I have a built-in iframe on the page (specifically a 360 degree photo of the product with controls for rotating and zooming).

```
<div class="iframe_css"><iframe src="/wp-content/uploads/2vr/file.html"></iframe></div>
```

Everything is fine in the desktop, the user can handle it. On the other hand, in mobile view, if the window is large enough to obscure the entire screen, the user cannot scroll in the y axis. How can I make the user scroll 'outside' the iframe while being 'inside the iframe'?

I have tried many methods with `overflow` etc.

```
iframe {
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

`pointer-events: none` works best, but can't change to `pointer-events: auto` when user clicks on iframe or hover it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 719px) { 
 iframe {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    iframe:hover {
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
}
```

How to deal with this?

How do I scroll the page when the iframe covers the entire screen?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you just have a scroll bar lookalike?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  It doesn't look neat...

Comment: OK so how do you want the user to be able to indicate that they want to scroll the main page not the iframe? Are there any touch actions which you absolutely know are not required when interacting with the iframe?

Comment: I think we got it wrong.  Imagine there is a page where an iFrame appears at some point.  It is large enough to fill the entire screen and the user cannot go up or down because touching the screen is as if it is inside the iFrame all the time and not on the original page ...

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked the question about touch events. Other implementations I've come across do things like a two finger touch to scroll the main page when you are over the iframe (assuming the iframe doesn't need this) or putting up arrows when the user double clicks - I've even seen full-screen 'apps' use 4 fingers in each of the 4 corners of the screen changing the action. Of course, the simplest would be to have a scrollbar just like the desktop user has, this is easily implmented and it's probably better to implement the functionality that have the thing look pretty :)